# Testing if list elements are numerical

Tags: list-manipulation, argument-patterns, arguments

I want to define a function with an argument, which is a list:

```
m = 10;
a = Table[k,{k,1,m}];
TestFun[listArg_] := Sum[listArg[[k]],{k,1,m}]
```

Now if I run the function,

```
TestFun[a]
```

it correctly calculates the sum to be 55.

Now I wish to define the argument of the function in such a way, that it only accepts numerical lists. For single arguments, I know this can be done for instance by:

```
TestFun[x_?NumericQ] := x
```

where x is a single number.
However for lists, `NumericQ` returns false. I tried defining the function by

```
TestFun[list_?MemberQ[#,_?NumericQ]]
```

but that did not work. Evaluting the function now simply returns:

```
TestFun[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}]
```

I'm on Version 11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
TestFun[listArg_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Sum[listArg[[k]], {k, 1, m}]

TestFun2[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]
```

> 55

or

```
TestFun2[listArg : {__?NumericQ}] := Sum[listArg[[k]], {k, 1, m}]

TestFun2[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]
```

> 55

You can also use the following as the argument of your function:

```
listArg : {_?NumericQ ..}
listArg_List?(And @@ NumericQ /@ # &)
listArg_List /; (And @@ NumericQ /@ listArg)
```